$e^{\pi}$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Prove that $e^{\pi}$  is transcendental over  $\mathbb{Q}$.

If we use the following theorem, then the problem is easy to solve.
Theorem (Gelfond–Schneider).
Let $a$ and $b$ be algebraic numbers with:

$a \neq 0$,
$a \neq 1$, and
$b$ is not rational.

Then $a^b$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Solution (question):  It is easy to note that  $e^{\pi} = (e^{-i \cdot \pi})^{i}=(-1)^{i}$, and we can use the previous theorem with $a = -1$ and $b = i$.

But i can't use that result. In this case, we need to use the following theorem.
Theorem.
Let $r$ and $s$ be algebraic numbers unequal to $0$ or $1$, then $\dfrac{log (r)}{log(s)}$
is either rational or transcendental.
But, i don't know to do it.

What do you mean by "transcendental over $\Bbb C$"?

In field theory, an element is called transcendental over a field if it is not the root of any non-zero polynomial with coefficients in that field.

$e^\pi$ is NOT transcendental over $\Bbb C$. It's a root of the polynomial $x-e^\pi \in\Bbb C[x]$

@JulianUribeCastañeda, that’s incorrect for one could construct a polynomial like ${(z-e^\pi)}^2$ and that would suffice your definition. In fact, the coefficients are supposed to be integer or rational.

Yes, it is my mistake. It is over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Don't use random tags like "galois theory" in your questions, they are clearly offtopic.

Suppose $e^\pi$ is algebraic. Then, setting $r=-1$ and $s=e^\pi$ in the theorem we get $\frac{\log(-1)}{\log e^\pi}=\frac{\pi i}{\pi} = i$ is either rational or transcendental, which is a contradiction.
A similar argument can be used to show that the second theorem is directly equivalent to the Gelfond-Schneider theorem.
